# scandir() in PHP far too slow

Tags: php, c, perl, scandir, readdir

The target directory has 10 million+ text files. `using $a = scandir()` in a web page is deadly slow. Need array results in less than two seconds. Filtering does not work (scans the entire list too)

all I can think of is to use a `perl` or `c` program to preprocess and stuff x thousand file names from the target directory into a file, tag the filenames in the target dir picked with a `.pi` at the end (or something) and use php's `file()` function to get the list from the file instead.

I need to open and work with each file before it gets stuffed into a table. fyi. I can't wait more than 1-2 seconds for the array to work on to be available.
Any assistance appreciated. Memory is not an issue. `hdd` space is not an issue, processor power is not an issue. the issue is getting a list in an array Fast while using a webpage front end. I can't wait because i am tired of waiting.

I tried using a brief fast c program with `opendir` and `readdir` but even it takes almost 4 minutes to scan the directory list. at least I could put a governor on it to limit to x files.

It seems the answer is to call the `perl` or `c` program which I can limit to x files and I can call this with `system()` or `backticks`. Then that list can be opened with `file()`...OTF... makes sense?

Comment: Any single directory with 10 million files in it will be slow — horribly slow.  A thousand files is too many, as a rule of thumb.  You need to reorganize the directory rather than worry about reimplementing in C (`scandir()` is implemented in C too — it won't make that much difference).

Comment: yeah, thought of that ... you are right, I'd probably have to rewrite it in assembly, and by the time i got that to work, scandir() would be done :-)

Comment: You'd be using the `opendir()` and `readdir()` system calls in the assembly, and they'd take a long time.  You probably need a multi-tier hierarchy of directories.  A simple scheme would take the first character for the first tier, the second (or first and second characters) for the second tier, and given the size of the system, probably the third (or first to third characters) for the third tier.  If the first three characters are alphabetic and are more or less evenly spread over a 26-letter alphabet (rather unlikely), you end up with about 600 files per third-level sub-sub-sub-directory.

Comment: What filesystem are you using?

Comment: Thanks Guys! in interim dumped most files into tmp folder workaround. php's scandir() works pretty well with 200K files at a time The C solution is def the final direction...babysitting the effort not so bad...

once scandir() does a 200K chunk of files another 200k chunk is moved in, etc etc this avoids rewriting tested code for now.

Am using XFS FS on /var partition and Fedora 21 OS on a 7TB raid 5 array controlled by a 5805Z Adaptec card that i picked up used on eBay for $80. All together pleased with this setup. Its basically an advanced commodity server...

Comment: *"I'd probably have to rewrite it in assembly"* You're missing the point. You've abused the file system by having so many entries in a single directory. Whatever language you choose (and nothing is likely to be significantly faster than well-written C) won't make any difference to the speed of the underlying file system.

Comment: *"Am using XFS FS on /var partition and Fedora 21 OS on a 7TB raid 5 array controlled by a 5805Z Adaptec card that i picked up used on eBay for $80"* You have seriously missed the point.RAID 5 isn't designed for speed, and you're probably sharing the disks on a single connection. Don't ask for speed from a budget redundant file system with millions of files in one directory.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is less PHP and more the filesystem.  Most filesystems do not work well with 10 million files in a single directory and performance starts to suffer badly.  You're unlikely to get much better performance out of rewriting it in C or Perl because the filesystem is simply overwhelmed and its performance has gone pathological.

First, switch from `scandir` to [`opendir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) and [`readdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php).  This avoids having to make a 10 million element array.  It also lets your program start doing work immediately before laboriously reading 10 million filenames.

```
if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        ...do your work...
    }
    closedir($dh);
}
```

Second, restructure your directory to have at least two levels of subdirectories based on the first letters of the filenames.  For example, `t/h/this.is.an.example`.  This will reduce the number of files in a single directory down to a level which the filesystem can better handle.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a `C` program that calls the `getdents` syscall. Use a large buffer size, say 5MB, and skip entries with inode == 0 to dramatically improve performance.

Solutions that rely on `libc` `readdir()` are slow because it's limited to reading 32K chunks of directory entries at a time.

This approach is described on the Olark Developers Corner blog linked below.

References:

- http://be-n.com/spw/you-can-list-a-million-files-in-a-directory-but-not-with-ls.html [old link](https://www.olark.com/developers-corner/you-can-list-a-directory-with-8-million-files-but-not-with-ls)
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html